# Cannot bootstrap an Express project using the express-generator tool

Tags: node.js, express, path, express-generator

I've installed `Node.js`, `express.js` and the `express-generator` globally.
 But when I try to create a new project using the `express` at the CLI, I get this error:

```js
    module.js:471
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'commander'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/express-generator/bin/express:3:15)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:
```

Error message advises to "re-install express-generator with `sudo`",
 even if I haven't changed the `node_modules` *variable path* or anything else.
I haven't yet found a working solution. Please help me out on this

Comment: Try removing express generator and reinstalling it again using npm.

Comment: Yes i tried that, but i still get the above error

Comment: I am not sure the issue is with the express generator. The error message says it cannot find module `commander`. `commander` is a dependency of `clean-css` which in turn is a dependency of `pug`. Try generating another project using another template engine, maybe ejs or handlebars let's see how that turns out.

Comment: What is so `ubuntu` about this problem? !! Also what you have written is different from what the error says

Comment: Try adding the `commander` module

Comment: @SuhailGupta because i develop my projects on Ubuntu and not in windows. There is no issue when working with windows. Only in Ubuntu. As i'm new to Ubuntu, please suggest me a way to add the commander module. Thanks.

Comment: @HimashaHarinda How do you add in windows?

Comment: @SuhailGupta in wondows i just have to install nodeJS and run `npm install express-generator -g` to install it globally. And then to create a project i just have to run `express` in the command line which cannot be done in Ubuntu as i get the above error.

Comment: @HimashaHarinda You do the same in ubuntu or any OS, that uses npm as a package manager. But the problem here is another module. To install commander use `npm install commander --save`

Comment: @SuhailGupta thanks, but im not saving express in the project, but globally. Therefore i dont think i have to use `--save` here. i ran the `npm install commander -g` but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you and this how I fixed
I uninstalled express generator then I updated npm and resinstalled express generator ,I re-arrange my path with this command PATH=~/npm/bin:$PATH and it works

Answer (score 0):

This error originates from how you installed the `express-generator` tool.

**Either**

- First run, `npm uninstall -g express.`
   Note that `express-generator` tool is to bootstrap `express@4` projects.
   Thus, you are advised to first *uninstall express globally* since it only generates `express@2 & @3` projects.
  This helps avoid conflicts.
- Then run, `npm install express -g express-generator`.
- For details, see official docs on [migrating to express@4](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html)

Based on your question, the above two steps should resolve the issues.

**Or**

In case the errors persist, then consider installing the latest `express-generator` tool.

For my case, i had `express-generator@4.0.0` but got the mentioned errors.

```js
// Env: Windows-10, Node-v10.16.3, npm-v6.11.2

C:\>npm list -g --depth=0
  C:\Users\...\npm
  +-- express-generator@4.0.0
  // other packages
```

Therefor, i reinstalled the tool...

```js
C:\>npm install -g express-generator
C:\Users\...\npm\express -> C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\express-generator\bin\express-cli.js
+ express-generator@4.16.1
added 7 packages from 6 contributors, removed 1 package and updated 3 packages in 19.032s

// This command should run, if all went well
C:\>express --version
4.16.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by uninstalling both packages. Don't forget to remove the from the whole system:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g express
sudo npm uninstall -g express-generator
```

After this I reinstalled both packages using

```
sudo npm install -g express express-generator
```

In case of error code `EEXISTS` it's possible that files like a symlink to '/usr/bin/express' were not removed. Those files can be overwriten using `--force`.